# Import scrapy error in Python 3.x

Tags: python, scrapy, python-import

I tried to import scrapy in Python 3.x.
I installed scrapy using cmd for "easy_install scrapy".
It seems well installed.
But when I try import scrapy in Python 3.x, I can see error.
I wrote code following this:

> import scrapy

And this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import scrapy
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.1.0rc3-py3.4.egg\scrapy\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from scrapy.spiders import Spider
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.1.0rc3-py3.4.egg\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scrapy.http import Request
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.1.0rc3-py3.4.egg\scrapy\http\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scrapy.http.request.form import FormRequest
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.1.0rc3-py3.4.egg\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 9, in <module>
    import lxml.html
ImportError: No module named 'lxml'
```

I can see that Python can't read module 'lxml'.
So I set up lxml in cmd for easy_install command.
And I wrote code:

> import lxml

And I can see only error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import lxml
ImportError: No module named 'lxml'
```

Why this happenning?
Scrapy only can read python2.x?
I am using Windows 8.1 64x, Python 3.x.

Comment: Check [`lxml` docs](http://lxml.de/installation.html#installation) on installing on MS Windows/. Try using `pip` instead of `easy_install`.You may also want to try installing Scrapy within [Anaconda distribution for Windows](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#anaconda) and use `conda install -c scrapinghub scrapy=1.1.0.rc4`

Comment: You are missing the parse library lxml install python-pip. I'm not sure but I don't think that scrapy runs in 3.x and if it does you won't be able to load dynamically generated content because phantoms for sure doesn't support 3.x

Comment: thanks guys. may be scrapy module only can read python 2.x. i knew new thing.

Comment: scrapy works on Python 3 from 1.1 (not released yet). You can install 1.1.0rc4 (release candidate) which works with Python 3.3+